# What is the best way to update an xml file often?

Tags: c#, xml, xna, xmlnode

I work on a small 3D voyel game like minecraft style.
In my game you can remove and add some cube.
Because of that i always need update/save my XML file. All the world is save in a xml file .
Everything work about add/remove node in my xml file , but the problem is about the performance !

Each time i need save in the xml file , the program need sleep for 1 seconde . This is really ugly in my game .. each time the player add a cube mean wait 1 seconde for save into my xml file.

Do you have some idea ?

Here is the way i save my xml file

Example (after remove a cube)

```
            XElement elementToRemove = elements
              .FirstOrDefault(
              x => (string)x.Attribute("min") == buildMin.ToString() &&
                    (string)x.Attribute("max") == buildMax.ToString());

            if(elementToRemove != null)
            {
                elementToRemove.Remove();
            }
            //Xdocument Class ~ call this function need 1 seconde
            XDocumentWorld.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"World\world.xml");
```

Comment: Do you really need to save the world after each block is added/removed?  You should just keep the world in memory, and save periodically or have the user click on Save World from a menu.  Another option is to use a SQL database to store the world data, instead of a file.  SQL will be much faster to add/remove records for blocks, they should get/save instantly.

Consider using SQL LocalDb as it is easy to deploy, free and lightweight.

Comment: one thing Ive done is to just append xml fragments to a text file, and then add the root node later

Comment: mhh ok thanks , no i don't really need save directly after. I already think about save into a xml file periodically , but if the application crash , nothing will be save

Comment: XML is a great file format for serialising data, but isn't a performant data structure that you should be updating in real-time! Read your data in at startup into a more suitable datastructure, and then write out to it whenever you decide to save. BUT important thing is that XML is not the 'live' datastructure for your game, it is just a serialisation format.

Comment: And what about using binary files like in Minecraft? It will be much faster 'cause you can save only modified chunks. NBT format is not so hard to understand. And if I'm not wrong MC save game every 30 seconds.

Comment: The point is that saving the world after each edit is just crazy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to save world state after each edit. Save the data before exiting the game or when a chunk (i.e., a region) is going to be removed from memory. Also, you can store just the list of player actions instead of all the blocks. To resume you regenerate everything using the same seed (assuming a random world) and then redo those actions.

Comment: Thank you , finally i save when i quit the game. It's work nice ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, you shouldn't be saving your XML every update. This is classed as bad code itself and therefore I wouldn't advise on using it. You should rather, instead, keep the information in memory and write on exit.

However, if you insist, you could in theory use another thread and schedule the code to write to the XML file every say 5 seconds reducing the load on the main thread and still keeping the functionality that you are requesting.

Have a look at the link below if you're unsure on how to use threads:

http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Comment: And you can even store only the list of edits as { X, Y, BlockId }